# variable labels cut off in ggtable

Tags: r, ggally

I created a table to characterize the clusters of my hierarchical clustering analysis (CAH). I did it using this code:

```
library(GGally)

ggtable(data1,
        columnsX = c("typo"),
        columnsY = names(data1)[1:17],
        cells = "col.prop",
        fill = "std.resid",
        legend = 1)
```

The issue I'm facing is that the labels of my variables do not appear correctly (they are cut off).

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?